# What Date types are timezone specific?

Tags: java, sql-server, timestamp

I have a calendar object with timezone specific. I want to update my sql server table using this object. However, it throws an error if I use calendar object in my unit test. I use hsqldb to test it with `datetime` as column type.

Therefore, I need to use different type for time. I tried using `Timestamp` object, it works, but it is not timezone specific. Here is my code:

```java
private SqlParameterSource getParameters(StudyEvent studyEvent) {
        MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        parameters.addValue(STUDY_ID, studyEvent.getStudy().getId());
        parameters.addValue(STUDY_DATE, new Timestamp(getDate(studyEvent.getStudy().getStudyDate()).getTimeInMillis()));

//studyEvent.getStudy().getStudyDate() returns long value of time (epoch time)
}

private Calendar getDate(long time) {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);
        return calendar;
}
```

In `new Timestamp(.....)` code, it won't be timezone specific which I need. What are other `Date` type object I can use so it is converted from `Calendar` and add it to sql server with timezone specific?

Edit:

I have a piece of code using prepared statement that allows me to use timestamp and timezone like this:

```java
private long insertStudy(StudyEvent event) {
        KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

        int records = jdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().update(connection -> {

            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(insertStudy, new String[] { STUDY_ID });
            int index = 1;
            statement.setTimestamp(index, new java.sql.Timestamp(Instant.now().toEpochMilli()), CALENDAR);
            return statement;
        }, keyHolder);
        return keyHolder.getKey().longValue();
    }
```

`PreparedStatement.setTimestamp()` looks like a possible solution, but I am not sure how to use `PreparedStatement` to `SqlParameterSource`..

Comment: Have you had a look documentation [Date and Time Data Types and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: As you can read [here](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#sgc_datetime_types) at the bottom of the section *DateTime types*, using a `java.time.OffsetDateTime` would be possible. It is not really time zone specific, but keeps an offset.